# login button not working in WKWebView loaded from URL in iOS 10 only

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, wkwebview

I am loading an external URL in `WKWebView` and it is having username and password textfield and a login button. Here the issue is ...login button is not working in iOS 10. Where as it is working fine in iOS 11.
Also I checked on device safari browser in iOS 10 and it is working fine there. Please help me with this issue .Any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the code of wkwebview here

Comment: let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        let webView = WKWebView (frame: customFrame , configuration: webConfiguration)
        webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        webView.uiDelegate = self
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webViewContainer.addSubview(self.webView)
        webView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(WKWebView.estimatedProgress), options: .new, context: nil)
        let urlString:String = "My URL"
        loadURLString(urlString)

Comment: can you please share the url also?

Comment: Actually it is a VPN based URL. So, I can not share.

Comment: login button redirects on another link or show popup?

Comment: Its redirects user to Dashboard Screen, Which is not a popup.

Comment: Try this ---   func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {
        // dismiss indicator
      
        // if url is not valid {
        //    decisionHandler(.cancel)
        // }
        decisionHandler(.allow)
    }

Comment: I have already tried this. But still not working. Actually no delegate calls when clicks on login button